# How to search for a javascript file in google?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, plugins

So I recently launched a jQuery plugin and people are downloading it, but I'm trying to figure out how I can tell where it's being used.  The only way I can think of is to try search for the .js or .css file somehow, maybe the folder name.

Is there anyway to search for this?

Comment: I can't see a way to do that passively. You could do it actively doing something similar to google analytics (your JS code would add a <script src='yourserver.com/your.js'/>) but that could affect the success of your plugin...

Comment: You could ask users to tell you about it. :) Something like "Do you use this plugin and find it useful? I'd love to hear about it. Drop me a line..."

Comment: @JScoobyCed Good note on both counts. I, for one, would remove such a "phone home" feature from a script I used, or not use it if it was required.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like such an obvious idea I'm sure you've thought of it and there's some problem, but how about taking some piece of your code, long enough to uniquely identify it, and search for that?  It definitely wont get everything, but maybe the results are better than nothing.